# SciLinux: libgfortran.so.3: version 'GFORTRAN_1.4' not found

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, gfortran

I am beginner in *nix systems, so there may be no sense in my actions :)

I'm trying to make a piece of software, written by our university team, run on a Scientific Linux 6.5. I am getting the whole time this error: "libgfortran.so.3: version `GFORTRAN_1.4' not found". I did a small research and have a small question: am I right, that according to RPM search result, there is no package for SciLinux, that includes GFORTRAN_1.4? I found RPMs with GFORTRAN_1.0 for SciLinux, but no RPMs with GFORTRAN_1.4 on this site:http://rpm.pbone.net

`locate libgfortran.so` returned:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4/libgfortran.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4/32/libgfortran.so
/usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3
/usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3.0.0
```

I did `objdump -T /usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3 | grep GFORTRAN_1.4` and it didn't return anything. I tried to update gcc and libgfortran via yum install and it didn't solve the problem.

`gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)`

So I would appreciate any help on this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GFORTRAN_X.Y is the name of a symbol node (google for "symbol versioning" if you wish to know more). For GCC 4.4 the highest version node is GFORTRAN_1.2. For GFORTRAN_1.4 you need GCC 4.6.

In practice, what this means is that you're trying to make some binary compiled on some newer Linux distro work on Scientific Linux 6.5. This is unlikely to work, please recompile the software on SL 6.5.